# Is it ok to attract a specialist's attention on your problem?

Tags: discussion, questions

Say I have read many post on a particular subject on SO, but none of them really solved my problem. And through all this reading, I realized that a particular user had a wealth of knowledge on the subject.

Is it ok to try and get him/her involved in my question? If yes, what would be a good way to do so?

I know that simply mentioning his/her username would not work since you have to have been involved in the question in order to receive notifications.

Comment: No.  You cannot ping anyone specifically to look at your question.

Comment: Chat rooms maybe ...

Comment: Good idea chat rooms.

Comment: No, it is not. This is not a "please be my personal consultant" site. If you have a question, post the question. If you ask it well enough, and it's tagged with the appropriate tags, people (including your *specialist*) will see it and answer. If you can't write it well enough to attract attention, work harder to write better questions. :-)

Comment: The usual way to increase attention is to start a bounty.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not. This is not a "please be my personal consultant" site.

If you have a question, post the question. If you ask it well enough, and it's tagged with the appropriate tags, people (including your specialist) will see it and answer. If you can't write it well enough to attract attention, work harder to write better questions. :-)

If you've made what you consider enough edits to improve it and still aren't getting answers, you can always start a bounty to try to get more attention focused on your question.

Also note [this has been asked before on the main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138706/is-it-possible-to-invite-somebody-to-answer-my-question-or-would-you-like-to-add).